# Can we have multiple job table each for a specific queue in laravel.?

Tags: php, laravel

I know that we can have multiple queues sharing a single database table. But what I am trying to do is to have every queue having its own separate job table in the database. If we can do this, please show me how.

I already tried to put multiple database entries in config/queue.php under connections as shown in the code.

```php
return [
    'connections' => [
        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'run_script',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],
        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'que',
            'queue' => 'notify',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],
    ],
];
```

All I am getting that both queues ( notify and run_script) are being dispatched to the `que` table. :(
I want the `notify` queue goes to `que` table whereas `run_script` queue goes to `jobs` table.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Just a quick notice - your array keys must be unique: you can have 2 database entries.

Comment: I tried unique keys but laravel only picking up the key named "database"

Comment: it's picking a key defined in your .env file by default.

Comment: why do you want to have different tables anyway? (just wondering)

Comment: My manager is curious and me also ... if we could have that then it would facilitate the maintenance of the application that we are working on.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but i believe i can solve your problem: http://laravel.at.jeffsbox.eu/laravel-5-queues-multiple-queues

You can make your queue config something like this:

```
'connections' => [

        'table1' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'TABLE1',
            'queue' => 'table1',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

        'table2' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'table2',
            'queue' => 'normal',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

        'table3' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'TABLE3',
            'queue' => 'table3',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],
],
```

And then dispatching job you just do:

```
$job = (new SomeJob())->onQueue('table1');
dispatch($job);
```

onQueue('queue_name') allows you to pick any queue (and in your case table) you want.

Comment: I looked at the solution that you proposed but all the queues which are low, medium, and high are referring to the same table 'Jobs' . I want all different queues refers to their own dedicated table. for instance 'low' to table1, 'medium' to table2, 'high' to table3.... is that feasible?

Comment: You can just change table under table param. You can change 'table' => 'jobs' to 'table' => 'whatever'. Just make sure those tables have proper structure and exist in your database

Comment: yes you are right.. but i already tried that and its working ... but changing the name of the table.... Lets suppose i created three tables ( which i already have) ... but couldnt find the way to dispatch the job to the desired table. I can change the queue name but its still dispatching it to the very single table.

Comment: Well if different queue names have different tables, you can select table by despatching a specific queue

Comment: I also think the same way... but could not find how to do so.. in laravel... If you know how to do that, I will be very thankful to you. I dont want dig deeper into laravel core as it might break the existing application.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Hey hi, i tried it but now its not even setting up migration for the given table names. But thanks,

Comment: That article is not correct. The configuration code he's shown is creating new connections, not new queues. Queues don't need to be configured, you just use the name when dispatching or constructing the job class.